# After changing directory url how to restrict access from real directory url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have website with `/admin` folder. And have changed to `/admin-cdn`
with `RewriteRule ^admin-cdn/(.*) admin/$1 [NC]`

Now I can access files with `/admin` and `/admin-cdn` url

I want to show 404 error when user hit `/admin` and `/admin/files.php` url

I have tried this It was working fine. But when I entered url `/admin` it will redirect automatically to `/admin/` and will give 404 error.

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} admin/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L,R=404]
```

But I want to show 404 error on `/admin` url don't redirect to `/admin/`. Because It will give hint like there is a folder.

Comment: Thanks for showing your efforts. Could you please do mention like FROM which url TO which url you want to redirect/rewrite? eg: `http://localhost:80/admin` should be served in backend by `http://localhost:80/admin/index.php` but url shouldn't change etc as an example, thank you.

Comment: _“Because It will give hint like there is a folder.”_ - and what would actually be wrong with that? Security by obscurity has never worked.

Comment: I want to redirect from ```http://localhost/buyer_seller/admin/``` to ```http://localhost/buyer_seller/admin-cdn/``` . but when user hit first url without backslash at end of url Ex: ```http://localhost/buyer_seller/admin``` it should show error with same url, it should not redirect at url with backslash ex: ```http://localhost/buyer_seller/admin/```

Comment: Since `/admin/` is an existent directory the redirection from `/admin` to `/admin/` is done by `mod-dir` an Apache module that's responsible for directories. If you want to remove this redirection, just add this line to your htaccess `DirectorySlash off` .